# double count statement MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have below table with Boolean column `has_object` which indicate each row has associated digital object or not.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| title      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| owner_uid  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| has_object | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have tried this query to obtain statistical information about each `owner_uid`. but in my table it returns wrong result:

```
SELECT 
  a.owner_uid, 
  count(b.pid) as count1, 
  count(c.pid) as count2  
FROM
  islandora_report a
  JOIN islandora_report b ON b.owner_uid = a.owner_uid AND b.has_object = 0
  JOIN islandora_report c ON c.owner_uid = a.owner_uid AND c.has_object = 1
GROUP BY a.owner_uid;
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `BOOLEAN` is merely a `0` or `1`, you can actually do one pair of `SUM()` without any joins to add up the column.

```
SELECT
  owner_uid,
  /* SUM() adds up all the 1 values */
  SUM(has_object) AS count_true,
  /* Invert the boolean with a case statement to get the inverse */
  SUM(CASE WHEN has_object = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS count_false
FROM islandora_report
GROUP BY owner_uid
```

There are other ways to invert the boolean than the method above. It's just the first that came to mind. You could also subtract the true sum from the total count, for example:

```
SUM(has_object) AS count_true,
COUNT(*) - SUM(has_object) AS count_false
```

Comment: It may be worth adding that, in MySQL, one can obtain the inversion with `SUM(!has_object)`.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, I couldn't remember if `!` negation was legal and didn't want to suggest it without certainty.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski and @eggyal: `SUM(has_object) AS count_true, SUM(!has_object) AS count_false`. I will accept this answer but also +1 for @ruakh true answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the joins; you can write:

```
SELECT owner_uid,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN has_object = 0 THEN 1 END) AS count1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN has_object = 1 THEN 1 END) AS count2
  FROM islandora_report
 GROUP
    BY owner_uid
;
```

Comment: is there any performance difference between different answers on this question?

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari: Mine and Michael Berkowski's should be equivalent. msangui's is qualitatively different, and I could imagine it performing differently -- perhaps worse, but perhaps better. The only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing:

```
SELECT
  owner_id, count(*), has_object = 1 as has_it
FROM islandora_report
GROUP BY owner_id,has_it
```

Comment: i forgot the second group, check it now